# Нужно убрать Jquery из Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, запрос

Убрать Jquery из yii2. Дело в том что скрипты самого yii задействуют jquery, и хочется просто вырезать jq из сайта вообще. Как поступить?

Comment: на нем завязана куча функционала, перестанет работать валидация, сортировка, фильтры и прочие плюшки ради которых Yii2 и любят

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не создавались директории в web/assets в конфигурационном файле, в разделе components пропишите

```
'assetManager' => [
   'linkAssets' => true 
]
```

Директории создаваться не будут, а будут создаваться ссылки на файлы. Это полезно при разработке, при каждой перезагрузке страницы будут обновляться css, js и прочие ресурсы.
Если хотите напрочь отключить, пишите так

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'css' => [],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```